# Encrypted ssd formatting

Tags: encryption, ssd, format

I have an encrypted ssd (that I need to sell) and I need to format it.

Can I assume that previous data, after a normal format (no shredding), will be not be accessible anymore due to the fact that encryption was in place? Or is same sort of safe erasure still required to assure that data are really lost for good?

Comment: Encryption should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If the ssd was encrypted correctly and the keys are not stored on it in plaintext for whatever reasons, the encryption will be enough and you don't even need to format it.
If you have doubts regarding the encryption process, you should do a safe erasure.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting, data shredding or overwriting can not ensure data sanitization on a SSD, because of wear-leveling mechanisms.
If the key was not stored on the drive, you are good to go. 
If the key was stored on the drive (for instance a laptop drive with LUKS). You would need to research if your drive supports ATA Secure Erasure, and if it is known to truly perform [secure erasure as intended](https://skrilnetz.net/the-truth-about-how-to-securely-erase-a-solid-state-drive-ssd/).

At the end of the day, it is more a question of risk management. If the risk incurred by the data loss is higher than the price of a second hand SSD, you may prefer to destroy the disk altogether.

Comment: Just to clarify I am talking about the internal SSD of a computer fully encrypted (not just the home folder) using the encryption that one sets while installing ubuntu, the one offered out of the box by the installer. I was getting asked the encryption password while the pc was booting so I guess that means encryption is applied to the whole drive and not just to the specific user. Is the key stored on the drive in my case? I surely remember that I have not done it myself, but even if I had done that, the file would have been encrypted as well no? I am a bit confused to be honest

Comment: Yes, the key is stored at the beginning of the encrypted partition. When you installed your system, a key was generated. The key was itself then encrypted with the password or passphrase you entered. So  unless you trust the secure erasure of your drive, you can not be 100% sure that nothing can be recovered. Although it is very unlikely.